# GStreamer unable to read input video when source stops and starts again

Tags: gstreamer

my gstreamer commands are working fine to convert `rtsp` video to `h 264` on Linux platform.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="source" ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoscale ! 
videorate skip-to-first=true ! videoconvert ! queue ! 
capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,format=(string)I420,width=(int)320,height=(int)240,framerate=(fraction)30/1,colorimetry=(string)bt601" !
x264enc byte-stream=true threads=1 me=1 subme=6 bitrate=100 speed-preset=1 ! video/x-h264 ! rtph264pay pt=96 mtu=1300 ! udpsink clients="IP:port"
```

But once source stops sending video feed and starts again then gstreamer pipeline does not read the new input stream, I need to restart gst command again to read new inputs.

Is there anyway to check if source stops sending video so that I can write a script and everytime script will start gst command if source behave like this.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this. I'm trying to run the gstreamer pipeling fetching fram an RTSP Source with MJPEG format which is slow and pauses every now and then. In the Meanwhile if the video pauses a bit, pipeline shows EOS (End of Stream) message and quit the program. Even tried Pipeline NULL -> PLAYING. Flushing Caps, etc.

Answer (score 0):

gst-launch is a great tool for testing, but you're limited in what you can do as far as signaling.  You can write an application around that pipeline and watch for the EOS (end of stream) message, and handle it however you want. See page 25 of the Application Writer's Guide: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/manual.pdf

In the mean time, rtspsrc has a timeout property, you can try setting that higher as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Link is Invalid

Comment: Link is Invalid!